# In Mac OSX Terminal, how can we determine tally up a count of .jpg files that do not have a certain word inside?

Tags: macos, unix, search, terminal

I recently downloaded all my photos from Google Photos using their Takeout option. They usually have issues with missing photos  so I am trying to make sure the number of photos I have online match the number I downloaded. The MAIN problem here is that Google Takeout will not only create a new folder for each day (2014-12-23) for example, but ALSO contains other files inside the folder such as `metadata.json` and `2014-12-23-edited.jpg`.

The edited part is if a photo was edited before. This means that if the original photo,

`2014-12-23.jpg` had edits, it will also include `2014-12-23-edited.jpg`.

Hence, my question is, how can I go through all the folder and tally up only `.jpg` files, and exclude any `.jpg` files with names that include the words "edited"? Is there a way to do this in Terminal in Mac OSX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
find /path/to/top/folder -iname "*.jpg" '!' -iname "*-edited.jpg" | wc -l
```

Explanation: the `find` command will search a specified folder and its subfolders for files matching the given criteria. `-iname "*.jpg"` matches filenames that end in ".jpg", and `'!' -iname "*-edited.jpg"` matches those that *don't* (that's the `!`) end in "-edited.jpg". `find` prints the paths of the files it finds, and `wc -l` counts the number of files (actually the number of lines, but unless you have linefeeds in your filenames there'll be one line per file).

Comment: So basically I would replace the `-iname c` with `-iname "*-edited.jpg"`?

Comment: @user321627 D'oh! Yes, that's what it was supposed to be (and I've fixed it now).

Comment: Thanks, this is super duper helpful!!

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, a slightly easier version:

```
find /path/to/start/at -iname \*.jpg | grep -vc "edited.jpg$"
```

The `-v` ignores lines ending in `edited.jpg` and the `-c` counts them.